# Android:Referencing canvas of CustomView?

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

This is `onDraw()` method of my custom view:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
        c.drawARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
        c.drawText("Text", 50, 50, p);
        canvas = c;

        canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 255);
        canvas.drawText("Text1", 20, 20, p);
//      canvas = c;
    }
```

Result of above method is a view with no color or any text.But if I comment first `canvas = c` and uncomment latest(at the last line in block) result will be a blue view with that "text1" is appeared in correct position.It looks like to the result of this override of `onDraw()`:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 255);
        canvas.drawText("Text1", 20, 20, p);
    }
```

Why referencing canvas of custom view can make changes in result?And also in first overriding,why the view appears with no color and  does not appear with red color?

**Edit:**

Suppose that c1,c2 are instances of class C,that are created separately.Now if we do:

```
c1 = c2;
```

Then all properties of c1 will be equal to properties of c2.Now my questions are:

1. Why when we use `canvas = c`,properties of canvas will not equal to c?(Custom view has no color or text,although c is red and has text)
2. What is different between first `canvas = c` and second one?As I said,result is different.

Answer (score 0):

I think the canvas memory is fixed in somewhere for rendering. you cannot change the canvas reference, which means you cannot use another memory block instead. therefore, you have to change the input memory content if you wanna draw something. do you agree my point?

Answer (score 0):

In the first override you are drawing on the canvas created from bitmap not the view's canvas, if you need to draw the bitmap on the view you need to call drawBitmap method of canvas class, on the object passed to you. What you are doing, would draw stuff on the bitmap that would be in memory and not affect what comes up in UI.

Comment: Please see your code again, you are creating a canvas c. then you set the canvas that you received to it. So you have not drawn anything on the canvas that you have received. To see anything on for the view you need to draw on the canvas received. What you are doing is creating a canvas performing draw operations on it and then nothing. canvas object ofcourse would have the same properties of canvas "c" obj. You cannot change canvas to reference to some object and expect that draw operations on it should affect the view, once you do canvas = c, you have lost the chance of drawing on the view

Comment: Are you able to do it this way http://stackoverflow.com/users/1043882/hasanghaforian

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#draw-with-canvas). I think this is the answer to your question.

Especially the part which says:

> Now your Canvas will draw onto the defined Bitmap. After drawing upon it with the Canvas, you can then carry your Bitmap to another Canvas with one of the Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap,...) methods. It's recommended that you ultimately draw your final graphics through a Canvas offered to you by View.onDraw() or SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas() (see the following sections).

**Based on your edit**

Please read my link, in some point states:

> Inside your View component's onDraw(), use the Canvas given to you for all your drawing, using various Canvas.draw...() methods, or other class draw() methods that take your Canvas as an argument. Once your onDraw() is complete, the Android framework will use your Canvas to draw a Bitmap handled by the system.

The key here is the phrase "the Android framework will use your Canvas to draw a Bitmap handled by the system". What you are doing in your example is to assign a canvas (c) from onDraw method which is for a different bitmap than the one android has create for the canvas, so no drawing will be performed. However if you comment the first canvas = c and uncomment the last what's happening is that you draw the blue text on the correct bitmap, actually you are going to get the same result without uncomment the last canvas = c.

Try using one of the drawBitmap functions of the original canvas object to transfer your bitmap to the one the system created.

What are you saying in your edits is correct, when you are doing canvas = c then it happens just that canvas is equal to c BUT now canvas is using a DIFFERENT bitmap from the one Android has created for the original canvas object and thus there is no drawing...

Hope this helps...